Dovecot imap_sieve plugin copies messages instead of moving messages
I have successfully configured Postfix + Dovecot + IMAP. And I just also installed spamassassin, spamc, spamass-milter, and configured imap_sieve plugin to combat spam.
Output of doveconf -n:
# 2.3.13 (89f716dc2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.13 (cdd19fe3)
# OS: Linux 5.10.0-33-amd64 x86_64 Debian 11.11 
# Hostname: mail.example.com
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext imapsieve vnd.dovecot.imapsieve
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = no
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Spam {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = %s
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  imapsieve_mailbox1_before = file:/var/lib/dovecot/sieve.d/default.sieve
  imapsieve_mailbox1_name = INBOX
  sieve_plugins = sieve_imapsieve
}
protocols = imap sieve
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/mail/domain.crt
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 20
  mail_plugins = " imap_sieve"
}

Contents of /var/lib/dovecot/sieve.d/default.sieve:
require "fileinto";

if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
    fileinto "Spam";
    stop;
}

And I tested my setup with:
# Executed from outside my network
wget https://spamassassin.apache.org/gtube/gtube.txt
swaks --to serrano@example.com --body gtube.txt

And it works. The email is successfully marked as spam (evident by X-Spam-Flag: YES in the headers). But the Sieve filter does not work as expected. It should move the message to my "Spam" folder, but instead it copies the message to the "Spam" folder, but only after I opened the message. The message remains inside the INBOX.
How can I make it so that the message gets moved to the "Spam" folder (not copied)? And why does the Sieve filter only work after I open the message in my email client?

Are you certain you configured the script in the correct location? It sounds like you want the script to execute on delivery (sieve), but you configured it to execute on IMAP actions (imapsieve) - so it would for example trigger on your mail client adding the \Seen flag.

The Dovecot documentation states that I need to use LDA or LMTP Server to use Sieve, but I use IMAP. That's why I opted for the imap_sieve plugin, which works with IMAP. I don't know if I can use LDA/LMTP in combination with IMAP.

You probably want to re-read the Dovecot documentation, specifically on what is special about imapsieve_mailbox1_before as opposed to sieve_before. You say you are using Postfix and Dovecot. It would be unusual for that use case to use anything other than LMTP (protocol for the MTA to submit mail) in combination with IMAP (protocol for the MUA to read mail). And your script does not look like it is meant to be called in response to IMAP actions, it looks like it is meant to be called on initial message delivery.

Your use case sounds like you meant to use

sieve_before: called when delivering incoming mail to users' mailboxes; whether that happens via dovecot-lda or LMTP; but instead configured
imapsieve_mailbox1_before: operating when messages are created or their attributes are changed by the mail user agent via the IMAP protocol.


Thank you, this was the solution! I followed these instructions to configure LMTP and sieve. Could you add that link to your answer?
